Kubernetes resource recommendations No Data
I am trying to set up krr in my minikube cluster. I have created a deployment for simple web-app. Then I have deployed Prometheus via Helm. Then I have installed krr locally and set up port forwarding to prometheus server for krr to connect.
But the krr report shows no data in recommendations. Also it has warnings that Prometheus does not return metrics:
...
WARNING  Prometheus returned no PercentileCPULoader metrics for Deployment default/krr-app/krr-app
...
WARNING  Prometheus returned no MemoryAmountLoader metrics for Deployment default/krr-app/krr-app
...

Judging by krr logs, it connects to prometheus successfully. I also get metrics when querying Prometheus in UI:
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="krr-app-85cddf485f-wpcdv"}[5m])

returns
{beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64", beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux", cpu="total", id="/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod9185dd9f_1850_4a8b_ae0b_3fdc85eb650a.slice", instance="minikube", job="kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor", kubernetes_io_arch="amd64", kubernetes_io_hostname="minikube", kubernetes_io_os="linux", minikube_k8s_io_commit="210b148df93a80eb872ecbeb7e35281b3c582c61", minikube_k8s_io_name="minikube", minikube_k8s_io_primary="true", minikube_k8s_io_updated_at="2024_12_02T13_05_19_0700", minikube_k8s_io_version="v1.34.0", namespace="default", pod="krr-app-85cddf485f-wpcdv"}

6.266166901647828e-07


Why krr report contains no recommendations?
